# Drag and drop the image into the BOX- selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I want to perform drag and drop in W3school web page using selenium. Code is working fine but output is not showing on the webpage.

link is :- http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

My code is :-

```
public String dragAndDrop(String object,String data){
    APP_LOGS.debug("waiting for popup closer");
    try{

        driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='drag1']"));
        WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='div1']"));
        (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).build().perform();
    }catch(Exception e){
        return Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL+" -- Unable to drag"+e.getMessage();

    }

    return Constants.KEYWORD_PASS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also interact with keyboard / mouse events using Actions class and robot class in Selenium. I have used `Robot` class to resolve your issue.

The `Robot` class is present in `java.awt` package. You can check all the methods in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/Robot.html).

```
public static void Task1() throws AWTError, AWTException, InterruptedException
{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop");

    driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//img[@id='drag1']"));
    WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='div1']"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);

    Point element3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='drag1']")).getLocation();
    int i=element3.getX()+800;
    int b=element3.getY()+250;

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(i, b);
    // Press left click of mouse
    robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    robot.delay(4000);
    robot.mouseMove(i+20, b-120);

    robot.mousePress( InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    driver.close();
}
```